# Dismiss View controller just after dismiising image picker

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller

I am having a view Controller lets say A.
I am presenting another View Controller lets say B on A.
In B's view will appear I am creating a object of MPMoviePlayerController and presenting it on B.

Now in when movie player stop playing movie I am doing follwoing:

```
[self dismissMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated];
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

But this is only dismissing movie player. I want to go on my A's view. 
How can I dismiss two viewcontrollers back to back.

Comment: why (-ve) vote?? Please explain whats wrong I asked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of your movie player is being dismissed and you are trying to dismiss your view.
Use following:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(dismissSelfView) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.6];

- (void)dismissSelfView {
      [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Also please take note that `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];` is deprecated in ios5 so better to use: `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:`. Please check [UIViewController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Hope this helps.